# How to connect lists with vertical lines?

Tags: lists, enumerate, text-decorations

So I want to write my notes where there are lists connected with vertical lines. I want the exact format displayed as in the below photo where in the nested lists the "main" line is stretched. Also I want this design to be added in the preamble. Thanks! [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a solution using `tcolorbox`.

I first created a new list `myenumerate` with the package `enumitem` to have `\Alph`, `\alph` and `\roman` numbering at each level, with a white background (using `\colorbox{white}`) behind the enumerate labels.

Then it is surrounded by a breakable `tcolorbox` via `\tcolorboxenvironment`, with a left borderline defined by the key `borderline west`.

The final result looks like this:

[image]

And below is the complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[myenumerate,1]{label=\colorbox{white}{\Alph*.}}
\setlist[myenumerate,2]{label=\colorbox{white}{\alph*.}}
\setlist[myenumerate,3]{label=\colorbox{white}{\roman*.}}

\tcolorboxenvironment{myenumerate}{blanker, breakable, before skip=6pt, after skip=6pt, borderline west={.6pt}{12pt}{gray!55}}

\begin{document}

Some text. \blindtext
\begin{myenumerate}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    \begin{myenumerate}
        \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        \begin{myenumerate}
            \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
            \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        \end{myenumerate}
        \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
        \item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    \end{myenumerate}
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\item Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
\end{myenumerate}
More text. \blindtext

\end{document}
```

Since you also mentioned the distance between items (i.e. stretched), the following version might suit you better:

```
\newlist{myenumerate}{enumerate}{3}
\setlist[myenumerate,1]{label=\colorbox{white}{\Alph*.}, itemsep=.5\baselineskip}
\setlist[myenumerate,2]{label=\colorbox{white}{\alph*.}, itemsep=0pt}
\setlist[myenumerate,3]{label=\colorbox{white}{\roman*.}, itemsep=0pt}

\tcolorboxenvironment{myenumerate}{blanker, breakable, before skip=\baselineskip, after skip=\baselineskip, borderline west={.4pt}{12pt}{gray!55}}
```

whose result would be like:

[image]

Comment: The vertical lines are centered on “A.” for example but OP has them centered on only the “A” part. I don’t know if that is important to OP though.

Comment: @Jinwen thanks for the response- but what if  there is way to much content for example: in one of the roman items there is a blindtext ('/blindtext[5]') that exceeds one page then the items are not displayed the way I like. Do you have any suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: @albinkabashi Ah, sorry, I forgot that nested breakable boxes do not behave in a very nice way. According to the documentation, "inner boxes are always unbreakable". You may consider changing `breakable` into `enforce breakable` though, which at least won't generate overfull text, but the result still wouldn't be perfect.

Comment: @albinkabashi As you are asking for lines around (actually only the left) the text, I believe it seems reasonable to consider putting it into a box. Otherwise one would have to record the exact positions of every enumerate label in the auxiliary file and then draw the lines accordingly, but since these positions are crossing the pages, performing these drawings with accuracy seems to be very hard. That would probably require using the `zref` referencing system and probably at least three compilation times --- of which I don't know very much details.